# Sort data in Excel using the 'Auto Filter' using VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2007, vba

I have AutoFilter in place in my sheet. I want to sort data using the AutoFilter itself and not by normal sort.

I want the client to see the down arrow on the autofilter button, which tells that rows are sorted on this key.

Any idea how to do that ?

I have 'sheet' as an object :

```
  sheet.Range("A2").AutoFilter then ??
  Or something else ??
```

Please help !

(Ensure the syntax for VB.Net and not VB Script)

I am a newbie..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To filter a range A1:A7, try:

```
Sheet.Range("$A$1:$A$7").AutoFilter(Field:=1, Criteria1:="MyFilter",         Operator:=XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues)
```

Make sure your are importing:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Edit:

```
sheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear()
sheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(Key:=sheet.Range("A1:A7"), SortOn:=XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues, Order:=XlSortOrder.xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)

With sheet.AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = XlYesNoGuess.xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = Constants.xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = XlSortMethod.xlPinYin
    .Apply()
End With
```

Comment: No.. Man, I don't want to filter values, I want to sort the values using the AutoFilter like what you can manually do in Excel using the AutoFilter.